# Unauthorized Operation When Querying Event Logs

Tags: c#, events, windows-7

I have the following code for querying some events on a remote computer:

```
filter = $"*[System[(EventID='5061' or EventID='5058') and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= {Timespan}]]]";
EventLogSession session;

using (var pw = GetPassword())
{
    session = new EventLogSession(
    "PCNAME",
    "DOMAIN",
    "USERNAME",
    pw,
    SessionAuthentication.Default);
}

var query = new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, filter)
    { Session = session };

var reader = EventLogReader(query);
```

When we reach the last line, `EventLogReader(query)` throws an error:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Where user `USERNAME` is a member of the `Event Log Readers` group on AD in the same domain. Is there some other group that he needs to be a member of? Or is there some way of configuring the `Event Log Readers` group to allow certain types of access?

Comment: have you resolve the issue, I am also facing same.

Comment: @ChandrashekarJupalli The user specified in `EventLogSession` needs to have local admin rights on the PC being queried

Comment: In my case, the user specified in EventLogSession had admin rights but still am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the user specified in in `EventLogSession` did not have local admin rights on the PC being queried.

After adding "USER" as a local admin on "PCNAME", I was able to query the logs successfully.

---

I thought this had already been set up, but because "USER" was added as an admin to all PCs via a script, the list of computers that it applied to must have been incomplete due to a bug in that script.